# Duplicated labels in Chart.js Stacked Bar Chart with Groups

Tags: javascript, object, graph, chart.js

I'm trying to create a stacked chart with groups in Chart.js but I'm ending with duplicated labels.
The graph should display two different sets stacked (let's imagine quantity of dogs and cats), grouped by year. Y-axe represents quantity, X-axe represents months.

Ideally the labels would be both type and year, like:

`dogs`, `cats`, `2022`, `2023`

I don't know if the issue is with my datasets or if I have to manipulate the labels. I've tried using `generateLabels` and `filter` according to [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html) but with no success.

Important to notice that the stacks and groups are dynamic so having some sort of hardcoded values will not work.

This results in duplicated labels for the type (dogs, cats) for each year available. See snippet for data and result:

```js
  const data = {
    "labels": [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March"
    ],
    "datasets": [{
        "label": "dogs",
        "data": [
          12,
          6,
          2
        ],
        "stack": "2022"
      },
      {
        "label": "dogs",
        "data": [
          2,
          20,
          5
        ],
        "stack": "2023"
      },
      {
        "label": "cats",
        "data": [
          2,
          5,
          7
        ],
        "stack": "2023"
      }
    ]
  }
  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      interaction: {
        intersect: false,
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true,
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true,
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to build the datasets differently in order to avoid duplicated labels? If no, how can I take advantage of `filter` or `generateLabels`?
If possible the available labels should be:
`dogs`, `cats`, `2022`, `2023`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, there is a solution you can try it hope it helps.

Ensure that each dataset in your chart represents one stack (e.g., dogs or cats).
Each dataset needs to have data for each month, and you should label them accordingly.
You need to configure the xAxes to stack the bars, and yAxes as per your quantity scaling.

```js
 var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Dogs 2020',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 9],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                stack: 'Stack 0'
            }, {
                label: 'Cats 2020',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7, 6],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                stack: 'Stack 0'
            }, {
                label: 'Dogs 2021',
                data: [14, 16, 7, 3, 6, 4, 10],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                stack: 'Stack 1'
            }, {
                label: 'Cats 2021',
                data: [8, 9, 6, 4, 5, 11, 8],
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                stack: 'Stack 1'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                x: {
                    stacked: true,
                },
                y: {
                    stacked: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.umd.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to achieve that but it isn't my prefered solution. I want separate labels for year and type. Further investigation led me to believe it's only possible using the generateLabels, filter and onClick options